# Why is the word "have" used instead of "are" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I read this sentence in my economics book:

> An expert team of UNO observed that the implementation and enforcement have the principal shortcomings of planning in India.

I strongly believe that "are" should be used instead of "have" after "enforcement" in this sentence. Am I right?

Comment: Grammatically speaking both verbs can fill the position, but would you tell me how you are sure that implementation and  enforcement can be described as shortcoming? For example,  a lack of both can be a shortcoming not themselves, IMO

Comment: An implementation can *have* shortcomings.  An implementation could also *be* a shortcoming.  Both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation can have shortcomings. An implementation could also be a shortcoming. Grammatically speaking both verbs can fill the position but with a small difference in meaning.